# List Filter View Based on Date's And Current Week Days

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list-filter

I am creating different list views for different pages so I can restrict access. Each list item contains dates for each day of the current week. The list items go back a couple months, so I would like to filter out everything that isn't apart of the current week. The Monday date for the list is calculated as `=(2-WEEKDAY(Today)+(Today))`.

Is there a way to add to the filter view to only show items where the Monday column is equal to the current Monday?

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following by initializing a variable and defining it as:

CurrentMonday =

```
formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(addDays(utcNow(), 1), dayOfWeek(utcNow()), 'Day'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

When I test the GET by using this variable in my QueryFilter for the SharePoint list, I get the following error:

```
{
   "odata.error":{
      "code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
      "message":{
         "lang":"en-US",
         "value":"The expression \"Monday eq 'formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(addDays(utcNow(), 1), dayOfWeek(utcNow()), 'Day'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')'\" is not valid."
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you check a post by @Jenny Hersko:
https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/show-this-week-only/

It is my understanding that your goal is to have a list view in SharePoint to **only show list items that are part of this current week.**

You can achieve this by adding 2 columns to your list:

| Column Name | Column Type | Formula | Formula Return type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Calc_WeekViewStart | Calculated (calculation based on other columns) | `=Calc_WeekViewEnd-7` | Date and Time (Date Only) |
| Calc_WeekViewEnd | Calculated (calculation based on other columns) | `=RandomDate-WEEKDAY(RandomDate,2)+7` **Where "RandomDate" is the column name for a "Date Only" column that holds any specific date.** | Date and Time (Date Only) |

Then you can config the list view to have a Filter:
[image]

Here is the `All Items` view VS. the `This Week Only` view:
[image]